# Using webfonts with sublime text 3

Tags: windows-7, fonts, sublime-text-3

Is there a way to use Google Web font with Sublime-Text 3 without admin privileges on Windows? I tried [sublime_webfonts](https://github.com/berendbaas/sublime_webfonts) but couldn't get it to work.

I can't install the fonts locally as I do not have admin privileges.

Comment: No, this is different. I looked at that question, but I am trying to find a way to make it work specifically with the editor and not system wide.

Comment: Also, am not looking to run any third party programs on my machine. Just get fonts to work with sublime text.

Comment: "without admin previleges on Windows" <-> "Using custom fonts without administrator rights" ... you see the similarity here?

Comment: "with sublime text 3" you see the difference here?

Comment: you realize that there was not really a way to make this work "system-wide" for a single user? you realize the chance to make this work for a single user PLUS limit the access to the font to a single program?

Comment: I never asked for a "system-wide" change. I am just looking to make it work for this application if there is an expert out there of the app.

Comment: i never claimed that you asked for system-wide. i just said: it's already hard to find a solution for system-wide-without-admin-rights. you are looking for something harder (coz you want to limit  what sublime3 sees).

Comment: I looked into the plugin "https://github.com/berendbaas/sublime_webfonts" and it indicates there is a way to make it work. However couldn't figure out exactly why. I posted the question only because it is hard after doing all my search and research..

Comment: that plugin does not what you think it does: it fetches to be used as part of a website / css; it also adds the correct references to that font via <link rel...> etc. it does not make these fonts available in sublime as fonts for the look of the editor.